# Codeigniter route a query string url

Tags: codeigniter, routes

How to use Codeigniter routes to redirect this url:

```
my_site.com/c_lancers/get_lancers?job=4&city=2
```

Into

```
my_site.com/c_router/get_slug_id/job=4&city=2
```

I tried this But didn't work:

$route['c_lancers/get_lancers?(:any)'] = "c_router/get_slug_id/$1";

Thanks A lot.

Answer (score -1):

Try this route

```
$route['c_lancers/get_lancers/(.+)'] = 'c_router/get_slug_id/$1';
```

This regular expression will capture anything after `get_lancers/` into `$1`

The CodeIgniter way to provide the example URL should be `my_site.com/c_lancers/get_lancers/4/2` instead of the query string `?job=4&city=2`

Comment: The thing is that there is no slash '/' after get_lancers

Comment: That's the point in providing the "CodeIgniter way". You can try `$route['c_lancers/get_lancers(.+)'] = 'c_router/get_slug_id$1';` It might work if `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` in `application/config/config.php`

Comment: The answer didn't work or the comment suggestion didn't work?